# Query-Validation-Engine

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I have two field like this,

```
<tr>
    <td align="right"><b>Min Capacity:</b></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="cbbMinCap" value="" class="validate[custom[integer],required,minSize[1], maxSize[4]] text-input"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="right"><b>Max Capacity:</b></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="cbbMaxCap" value="" class="validate[custom[integer],required,minSize[1], maxSize[4]] text-input"/></td>
</tr>
```

My goal is to validate Min Capacity < Max Capacity. I checked in `jquery.ValidationEngine.js` but can't found it. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use custom validation

i have given full codes now

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("lessthan", function(value, element, params) {
                    return this.optional(element) || value <$(params).val();
      }, jQuery.validator.format("Please enter the correct values"));

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
           $("form").validate({
              rules: {

                    cbbMaxCap: {
                                required:true,
                                lessthan: "#cbbMinCap"// this is id you want to compare tp this input
                                },
                    cbbMinCap:{

                            required:true,
                        },  
              }
            });

    });
 </script>
```

for input fields give a id (or class)

```
<input type="text" name="cbbMinCap" value="" class="" id="cbbMinCap"/>
<input type="text" name="cbbMaxCap" value="" class="" id="cbbMaxCap"/>
```

you can use validation engine from http://jqueryvalidation.org

Comment: ah,where should I put it in.I have posted the code below.
Please forgive my stupidity

Answer (score 2):

you can use your own validations

see http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/